# Swift - How to JSONDecode with codable for JSON of nested arrays (where arrays without keys or names as per example given)

Tags: json, swift, decoding, codable

I am new to Swift and Codable approach. I have to decode the following JSON structure, through **Codable** approach in Swift project.

```
[
    [
        [
            {
                "id": "58",
                "parentCat": "7",
                "catFirstTitle": "freedom to"
             },
             {
                "id": "40",
                "parentCat": "5",
                "catFirstTitle": "freedom to"
             }
        ],
        [
            {
                "id": "58",
                "parentCat": "7",
                "catFirstTitle": "freedom to"
             },
             {
                "id": "40",
                "parentCat": "5",
                "catFirstTitle": "freedom to"
             }
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            {
                "id": "58",
                "parentCat": "7",
                "catFirstTitle": "freedom to"
             }
        ]
    ]
]
```

I could not find any examples of decoding multi level jsonArrays without key names. Any pointer or example will be a great help to me.

Comment: SwiftUI has nothing either to Codable or to JSON, it's about constructing UI.

Comment: @Asperi and pawello2222 thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple struct:

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let id: String
    let parentCat: String
    let catFirstTitle: String
}
```

And decode as a nested array object:

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([[[Item]]].self, from: jsonData)
```

---

Note that the result will be of type `[[[Item]]]`.

You may want to flatten it as well:

```
let flattened = result.flatMap { $0 }.flatMap { $0 }
```